# WIndows Batch Script to remove multiple special characters from a text file

Tags: windows

I have a text file which has lot of special characters. From that test file, I would like to remove three special characters(~ œ <). Can someone please provide me a script to address my need? I tried with some scripts but it doesn't seem to be working for the character ~.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to execute this, download it [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)  -

```
sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g" file.txt
```

If you have latest, Windows 7 or higher version, you can do something like this in PowerShell

```
Get-Content file.txt | foreach { $_ -replace '[^\w\d]' } | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 file.new.txt
```

OR, Download [Ruby for windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

```
C:\>ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/[~)œ\[\]<]/,"")' file
```

Thanks!